# Cómo asignar el valor de un diccionario al elemento de una lista

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Pues eso, ¿cómo relaciono el valor de un diccionario a los elementos de una lista teniendo en cuenta que la clave y el elemento de la lista es el mismo?

Planteo lo siguiente:

```
POWER = { 'Fireball': 50, 'Lightning bolt': 40, 'Magic arrow': 10, 'Black Tentacles': 25, 'Contagion': 45 }

gandalfspells = ['Fireball', 'Lightning bolt', 'Lightning bolt', 'Magic arrow', 'Fireball', 'Magic arrow', 'Lightning bolt', 'Fireball', 'Fireball', 'Fireball']

sarumanspells = ['Contagion', 'Contagion', 'Black Tentacles', 'Fireball', 'Black Tentacles', 'Lightning bolt', 'Magic arrow', 'Contagion', 'Magic arrow', 'Magic arrow']

spells=[]
for spell in (gandalfspells) and (sarumanspells):
    if spell == POWER('key'):
        listagandalfspells.append('valor')
print("Spells power are", listagandalfspells)´
```

Answer (score 0):

Te éstas haciendo un lio al iterar sobre la lista y acceder al valor del diccionario usando cada item de la lista como clave, tienes variaas opciones, de peor a mejor, aunque ésto es opinable:

### No comprobar si la clave existe previamente

**Solo si estás seguro que los items en la lista está siempre en el diccionario**, si es el caso, es la forma más simple y eficiente, si no lo puedes asegurar es la peor de todas...

```
for spell in gandalfspells:
    valor = POWER[spell]
    listagandalfspells.append(valor)
```

### Usar el operador de pertenencia para saber si la clave existe

```
for spell in gandalfspells:
    if spell in POWER: # La clave existe en el diccionario
        valor = POWER[spell]
        listagandalfspells.append(valor)
```

---

### Usar manejo de excepciones

```
for spell in gandalfspells:
    try:
        valor = POWER[spell]
    except KeyError: # La clave no existe en el diccionario
        pass
    else:
        listagandalfspells.append(valor)
```

---

### Usar el método `dict.get()`

```
for spell in gandalfspells:
    valor = POWER.get(spell)
    if valor is not None:
        listagandalfspells.append(valor)
```

---

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
for spell in gandalfspells:
    if (valor:= POWER.get(spell)) is not None:
        listagandalfspells.append(valor)
```

---

En definitiva, podría ser:

```
POWER = {
    'Fireball': 50,
    'Lightning bolt': 40,
    'Magic arrow': 10,
    'Black Tentacles': 25,
    'Contagion': 45
    }

gandalf_spells = [
    'Fireball', 'Lightning bolt', 'Lightning bolt', 'Magic arrow', 'Fireball',
    'Magic arrow', 'Lightning bolt', 'Fireball', 'Fireball', 'Fireball'
    ]

saruman_spells = [
    'Contagion', 'Contagion', 'Black Tentacles', 'Fireball', 'Black Tentacles',
    'Lightning bolt', 'Magic arrow', 'Contagion', 'Magic arrow', 'Magic arrow'
    ]

lista_gandalf_spells = []
for spell in gandalf_spells:
    valor = POWER.get(spell)
    if valor is not None:
        lista_gandalf_spells.append(valor)

lista_saruman_spells = []
for spell in saruman_spells:
    valor = POWER.get(spell)
    if valor is not None:
        lista_saruman_spells.append(valor)


print("Gandalf spells power are", lista_gandalf_spells)
print("Saruman spells power are", lista_saruman_spells)
```

> ```
> Gandalf spells power are [50, 40, 40, 10, 50, 10, 40, 50, 50, 50]
> Saruman spells power are [45, 45, 25, 50, 25, 40, 10, 45, 10, 10]
> ```

Si buscas eficiencia, usar listas por compresión es una buena opción, por ejemplo:

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
lista_gandalf_spells = [
    valor for spell in gandalf_spells if (valor:= POWER.get(spell)) is not None
    ]
lista_saruman_spells = [
    valor for spell in saruman_spells if (valor:= POWER.get(spell)) is not None
    ]
```